# Wrap function with promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Okay, so I've almost got the hang of promises.

I'm trying to figure out how to place a promise within view_functions so that the return works.

```
function loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data){

    var this_app_data = [];

    function viewFunctions(){

        for (i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {

            this_app_data[i] = window[view_functions[i]]();

        }
        for (i = 0; i < this_app_data.length; i++) {

            this_app_data[i].then(function(this_d) {

                append_data = append_data + this_d;

            });
        }
        return append_data;
    }

    //return
    return viewFunctions().then(post_app_data => {
        return post_app_data;
    });
};
```

Comment: The `then` in the return statement doesn't do anything. Is it meant to be doing something?

Comment: You want `Promise.all(this_app_data)`

Comment: @Bergi the function is camelCase while the argument is snake_case, so they don't conflict. But that threw me off for a second too.

Comment: No Bergi, look closely, one has an underscore, the other does not.

Comment: You really should pass an array of functions, not an array of names of global functions

Comment: lol no problem...

Comment: They are coming from a JSON object. Therefor they have to be names.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the resolution of those names has to happen here.  It could be in the calling code.

Comment: Doing it here makes this function much harder to test.

Comment: If you could provide an example of something better that would be awesome...

Comment: @PeterMader Yes it does, but that doesn't need to be seen here.

Comment: @RyanChristopher If they have to be names, at least don't make them names of global variables but rather names to look up in a `Map` or local object.

Comment: i don't understand why a very common duplicate needs so much discussion. make an array of promises, wait on them to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet should be equivalent to what I think you are trying to achieve:

```js
function loadViewFunctions (view_functions, initial_append_data) {
  // retrieve the functions and calls them
  const promises = view_functions.map(f => window[f]());
  return Promise.all(promises).then(
    // join the results together
    results => results.reduce((acc, this_d) => acc + this_d), initial_append_data)
  );
}
```

It uses

- `map` to iterate over an array and create a new one and
- `Promise.all` to wait until all promises that you give to it have resolved

As others have mentioned in the comments, don't use function names to access global functions. Pass an array of functions instead.

Comment: There is an error in the code.

Comment: Honestly so confused by this code.

Comment: You were right, the error has been edited out. What parts of the code do you not understand?

Comment: still an error lol, and i understand it now...

Comment: Fixed error... works. Thank you good sir!

Comment: Good to hear that. I must admit my code is a little too succinct and perhaps hard to understand.

Comment: You know your stuff. Hard to find people like you.